# Nonlethal damage up to max HP instead of current HP, as feat or item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, class-feature

I am playing a Kineticist from the *Occult Adventures* Playtest, and am looking for a specific effect to help with the Burn class feature: the ability to take nonlethal damage up to my maximum HP, rather than current HP, before losing consciousness.

This feature is available to the Medium class, also in the *Occult Adventures* Playtest, through the Neutral Constitution spirit called "The Teamster". The Greater Spirit Power for this spirit is called "Knife's Edge", and is worded as follows:

> **Knife’s Edge (Greater, Su)**: Double your Constitution
>   score before adding the Teamster’s spirit bonus to
>   determine when hit point damage kills you. If you are
>   not immune to nonlethal damage, when you are at 0 hit
>   points or below, convert the first 5 points of damage you
>   take from each attack to nonlethal damage. **You are not
>   knocked unconscious by nonlethal damage unless you have
>   as many points of nonlethal damage as your maximum hit
>   points, rather than your current hit points.** (Emphasis Mine)

But, because the Greater Spirit Power is a 13th level Medium class feature, it would be a very long wait for multi-classing (Unless Variant MultiClassing somehow allows it to work) just for that benefit. This is why I'm looking for something that doesn't require a lot of investment in another class (Though I am fine with a heavy feat or gold investment.)

Comment: @KRyan

Thanks for the edit, not 100% on formatting yet.

Comment: Not a problem. One thing I did not know is this “VMC” – I am not familiar with that abbreviation. It would improve this question if you could un-abbreviate it.

Comment: @KRyan. My bad. I'll go ahead and un-abbreviate it. For future reference, it stands for Variant-Multiclassing, a sub-system introduced in Pathfinder Unchained. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Variant-Multiclassing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## An Imperfect Solution:

So, it's not as tidy as the Teamster's implementation, but I think I've found a somewhat quick and dirty solution to this problem.

I found a 7th level feat called [Flagellant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/flagellant):

> **Prerequisite(s):** Endurance, character level 7th, worshiper of Zon-Kuthon.
>
> **Benefit(s):** You gain a +4 bonus on saving throws against pain effects.
>   Also, you suffer no adverse effect when your nonlethal damage equals
>   your current hit points, and you become staggered when your nonlethal
>   damage exceeds your current hit points. You never fall unconscious due
>   to nonlethal damage.
>
> **Normal:** When your nonlethal damage equals your current hit points, you
>   become staggered. When your nonlethal damage exceeds your current hit
>   points, you fall unconscious.

This at least removes the problem of dropping unconscious due to non-lethal damage. The downsides are the staggered effect, and the fact that you must worship Zon-Kuthon (PFSRD is unable to use the name for legal reasons.)

To counter the staggered effect, there is a ring called the [Ring of Ferocious Action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-ferocious-action):

> This ring allows its wearer to persevere through physical or mental trauma that hampers his actions. The ring has 5 charges, which are renewed each day. At the start of his turn, if the wearer is staggered, as a free action he may spend a charge to activate the ring and ignore the staggered condition until his next turn.

At 3000gp a pop, someone could buy a couple of those rings, and use them as an absolute last resort. Not exactly what I'd like, but I have a feeling it's the easiest way, and while being staggered is a less than ideal condition, it's 100% better than unconscious.

Until I find another item, a spell, or a feat that allows you to ignore the staggered condition, this seems to be my best option.

Comment: I figured I'd throw this in a comment, because it's not really related to what I was originally asking, but the Boots of the Earth from Inner Sea Gods (Also where Flagellant is from) would be a nice way of dealing with the damage out of combat.